# Writing a bash script to run a java program

Tags: java, bash

I'm rank new to bash thus the question.
I've a java program that I've exported as a .jar.
This file when run as

```
java -jar somefile.jar
```

goes into an infinite loop and awaits a file name. Based on the correct file path it generates an output.

How do I write a bash script to do automated testing of this project. 
I need the scrip to do the following -

```
Run the program, which is run the same command
provide an array of 5 files as an input to the program
For each file write the output to an log file.
```

Comment: Does the filename get passed to the java program, or do you have to enter it into the program by hand?

Comment: No the file name is not passed into the program as an argument, but one has to enter it by hand and then enter quit to quit the program.

Comment: There. I got you something that should work for you. Feel free to comment on it, suggest improvements, and accept my answer if you use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

files="$@"

for i in $files;
do
    echo "Doing $i"
    java -jar somefile.jar <<< "$i"
done
```

Make sure you `chmod u+x filename` it first. Then call it like this:

```
./filename firstfile secondfile thirdfile etc.
```

**Other:**

As sjsam pointed out, the use of `<<<` is a strictly bash thing. You are apparently using bash ("I'm rank new to bash..."), but if you weren't, this would not work.

Comment: @sjsam: Thanks. (Sadly, some of us aren't as aware of all the differences. Thanks for the comment--it's appreciated.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose my java program is HelloWorld.java. We can run it in 2 ways:

1st using executable jar

2nd by running java class from terminal

create a new text file and name it `hello.sh`

In `hello.sh`

```
!/bin/bash
clear
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

Save it and open terminal:

1 navigate to directory where your `HelloWorld.jar` is present

2 give permission to terminal to run the bash script by using the following command

```
sudo chmod 754 hello.sh
```

3 run you script by running the following command

```
./hello.sh
```

Comment: Could you explain the second way? "2nd by running java class from terminal" I am struggling to find any documentation on this.